# Does a child born outside the EU qualify for an EU passport if the mother is from an EU country?

Tags: eu-citizens, eu-spouses, passport, children, poland

If a child is born to a non-EU member father and an EU-member (egPolish) mother outside of the EU - say in the country of the father's residence - does that child qualify for the same passport as the mother?

Comment: It depends on the laws of the mother's country of origin regarding nationality. If you know, we can give a direct answer (or you can google it).

Comment: The mother is a Polish citizen.  I found that the child would be a Polish citizen, but still somewhat unsure if the child definitely qualifies for an EU passport then.

Comment: If the child is a Polish citizen, the child qualifies for a Polish passport (subject to any requirements specified in Polish law).  The term "EU passport" is shorthand for "a passport of an EU country"; there's no actual passport issued by the EU to European Union citizens by virtue of their European Union citizenship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [child born to a Polish citizen](https://polaron.com.au/info/eu-citizenship-faqs/) outside of Poland is automatically a Polish citizen.

Polish citizenship qualifies the child for a Polish passport. There is no specific EU passport. Each member country's passport is evidence of EU 'citizenship' and all of those rights and responsibilities.